# How can I send emails from a web server to an external domain via Exchange?

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange, web-server, smtp

We have a web server that sends emails via PHPMailer, this works fine when sending emails to email addresses on the domain. However, when sending emails to addresses outside the domain it fails with this error:

"SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: example@otherdomain.com"

I have tried setting up a recieve conntector for the web server's IP address and opening it to anonymous users etc., but it's still showing the same error. This is Windows Server 2008.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by commenting out the TLS line in my PHP code:

```
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to grant any 3rd party solution the rights to relay emails via your Exchange server ([here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277329.aspx) is a very old, but still valid document to start with). The exchange server should then send the emails into the internet the say way your existing Exchange users do that.

However multiple points might prevent that:

- Sender email from your 3rd party solution isn´t OK
- The 3rd party environment isn´t in the white list on your Exchange server
- The needed port between your Exchange Server and your 3rd party solution isn´t open
- Your configuration required a TLS connection (e.g. startTLS) but the SSL certificate isn´t trusted on the 3rd party solution (if you wish to troubleshoot that you can check the following [howto](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/353-resolved-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.html)).
- ...

The best option to troubleshoot that would be to open a telnet session on the 3rd party solution and connect to your exchange server ([see here if you need an example](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html)). Then try to send an email via telnet. Based on the telnet test you will get an SMTP specified error message you should add to your posting, so that we can pick that up.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by commenting out the following line in my PHP code: $mail->SMTPSecure =  'tls'.